# I don't want the captions to show in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I've compiled the list if figures at the beginning of my document using \listoffigures, and the list of figures has the entire caption of each figure shown in the list.  I don't want the captions to show in the list of figures.  In the list of figures I just want the figure number on the left, the line of dots in the middle, and the page number on the right.  How do I get rid of the captions in the list of figures?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Try with `\caption[]{caption text}` although I don't really seem to understand the purpose of such a list of figures. How could this help a potential reader to find a certain figure in the text? Isn't it more likely that someone  remembers part of the caption than the figure number itself?

Comment: @leandriis - Actually, an empty [short caption] eliminates the LOF entry altogether.  \caption[\null]{...} or some other invisible text would be better.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I can't confirm this. The following code results in [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI91q.png) which is exactly what OP requested. At least if I understood " In the list of figures I just want the figure number on the left, the line of dots in the middle, and the page number on the right." correctly. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption[]{figure caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption[]{second figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`